# Tomcat Server Cannot assign requested address: connect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to run a spring boot application but the embedded Tomcat keeps on experiencing an error. I've tried changing the port to any unused port number.

Attaching most of the logs for your reference:

```
   Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76) ~[na:na]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably is because another process is using the two ports you've tried.

Did you tried to list the ports that are being used?

On MacOS you can try running this in your terminal:

```
lsof -nP  | grep LISTEN
```

If you are using Windows, you can run this in your powershell:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort YourPortNumberHere).OwningProcess
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the insight but I've actually checked the used ports and made sure to use a unique or unused one.

Comment: @Ando That information should go into your Question, so users don't try to guess at what could be the issue.

Comment: I've already specified it in my question.

"I've tried changing the port to any unused port number."